# Current memory usage in Lisp

Tags: lisp, memory-management, common-lisp

I need to find out, from within a Common Lisp program, how much memory is currently being used.

I'm given to understand there is no portable method (the standard function `room` prints the information to standard output in text form instead of returning it as a value), but `sb-kernel:dynamic-usage` works in SBCL.

What are the equivalents in other Common Lisp implementations? Or is there another way to solve this problem I should be looking at?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may not help you much, but anyway:

You can capture the output of (room) and parse it.

```
(with-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
  (room))
```

Above returns a string with the output of ROOM.

Additionally it may help to request the memory size of the process via an external call to a standard unix command (if you are on Unix).

Answer (score 4):

For things which virtually every implementation supports, but not in the same way (because it's not in CL), one common approach is to make a library called [trivial-](http://www.cliki.net/trivial)whatever.

If you started a package like `trivial-memory`, and supplied the first implementation, I'm sure we could get everybody to contribute the function for their own favorite Lisp compiler in short order.  :-)

Comment: I could certainly create a trivial-memory package on github, and fill in the cases I know. You seem optimistic about the prospects of getting contributions :-) do you know of an appropriate place for announcing these things, or is there some other aspect of the Lisp community you have in mind that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: I'm only optimistic because it seems like just one small function call, each, you need to get.  :-)  If I was trying to get something like this announced, I might try getting Xach to blog about it, which means it'll get on planet.lisp.org.  If there's one or two common implementations you can't get answers to, you could always post a specific question about it here on S.O., too.  Good luck!